# Override the enter key, but keep default behavior for other keys in a wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, overriding, key-bindings

It really bothers me that the pressing the enter key in a Datagrid moves the selection down one item, I'd like to be able to decide what it does in a normal keydown event.

So what I did was create a new class that inherits DataGrid and override the OnKeyDown event and use that as my datagrid.

This creates a whole new set of problems, since I apparently have to rewrite all the other keypresses (arrow key navigation, shift+arrow key selection, pgup/pgdn, etc..). I've been trying to hack it, but it just seems so pointless spending time rewriting something that has already been written and probably better then whatever I'll come up with.

So how can I make the enter key do what I want without messing with the other default keybindings of the datagrid?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u please share u r code. I have the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if the key pressed is enter, if it's not, call the base event handler for KeyDown (something like `base.OnKeyDown(sender, args);`)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And now I know what the base keyword is for :D  Thank you

Answer (score 11):

You will need to bind a `PreviewKeyDown` handler to the Datagrid and then manually check whether the key value is  `Key.Enter`.

If yes, set `e.Handled = true`.

Comment: Wouldn't this just suppress the keypress and make the enter key do nothing?

Comment: Yes, on the datagrid atleast. Isn't that the desired effect?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I don't want the default enter key behavior, but I still want to be able to use it in a KeyDown event to run my own functions.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler implementation. The idea is to capture the keydown event and if the key is "Enter", 
decide in what direction you wish to traverse.

FocusNavigationDirection has several properties based on which the focus can be modified.

```
/// <summary>
/// On Enter Key, it tabs to into next cell.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void LiquidityInstrumentViewsGrid_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PreviewKeyDown` with `Handled = true` is a **bad** solution. It would stop handling Key on the tunelling phase and never bubble the key event up. Simply speaking it would eat any Enter key presses. That  meant that upper panels, would never get `KeyDown` event (imagine that your Window accepts something on ENTER `KeyDown`...).

The right solution is what Anthony has suggested: to leave the `Handled = false`, -- so it continues bubbling -- and skip handling Enter inside DataGrid

```
public class DataGridWithUnhandledReturn : DataGrid
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach works great, but the example doesn't handle **Shift+Enter**. You should check if the modifier keys are equal to `ModifierKeys.None` or `ModifierKeys.Shift`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works similiarly to winforms, for the key presses that you aren't handling, than flag the handled as false, and it will pass the key press along.
[KeyEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx)

Handled Gets or sets a value that indicates the present state of the event handling for a routed event as it travels the route. (Inherited from RoutedEventArgs.)